# Images cannot be saved in db

Tags: python, html, django

Images cannot be saved in db.I wrote in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):
    form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.save()
            return render(request, 'registration/photo.html')

    else:
        form = UserImageForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

in models.py

```
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True,)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True, )
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True, )
```

in forms.py

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image',)
```

in profile.html

```
<form action="/accounts/upload_save/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
            {% csrf_token %}

                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="file_select btn-lg">
                    File Select1
                    <input id="file1" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">

                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn-lg file_select">
                    File Select2
                    <input id="file2" type="file" name="image2" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
          　　
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                  <span class="btn-lg file_select">
                    File Select3
                    <input id="file3" type="file" name="image3" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
                  </span>
                </label>
          　　　 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">

              <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">

              <input id="send" type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
          </form>
```

When I uploaded 3 images from html and SEND button, no image was not saved.But after sending SEND button,photo.html is shown, so program was successful.I cannot understand why 3 images cannot be saved.I wrote data.save().How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Answer (score 0):

In form you need to specify all fields what will be updated:

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = ('image1', ''image2', 'image3')
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes, but when I put SEND button, images cannot be uploaded.always in views.py  program goes into `else:
        form = UserImageForm()
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})` .How should I fix this?

Comment: @user7676799 add forms error to html to check what is going wrong: `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` `{{ form.image1.errors }}` `{{ form.image2.errors }}` `{{ form.image3.errors }}`

Comment: @user7676799 you have `name="image" ` in html, but in model there is `image1` field. Try to change name to image1 `name="image" `